# Parse error for /etc/fstab trying to mount smb share

Tags: fstab

I am using FileMaker Server 19 in CentOS 7.8 and trying to mount a smb share for the backup of databases.

I have entered into fstab:
"//172.30.x.x/CentOS /opt/FileMaker/FileMaker\040Server/Data/Backups cifs username=mylogin,password=mypassword, uid=989, gid=1004 0 0"

When I run "mount -a" I get the error "mount: /etc/fstab: parse error: ignore entry at line 13."

The above is line 13...

The cifs command runs fine in the command line so I know the details are correct.

Can anyone see any obvious errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the extra spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy/pasted it, then I see that uid and gid have a " " before them, yet all options should be concatenated (no spaces).
BAD:

```
//172.30.x.x/CentOS /opt/FileMaker/FileMaker\040Server/Data/Backups cifs username=mylogin,password=mypassword, uid=989, gid=1004 0 0
```

Good:

```
//172.30.x.x/CentOS /opt/FileMaker/FileMaker\040Server/Data/Backups cifs username=mylogin,password=mypassword,uid=989,gid=1004 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Did not pick-up on this syntax rule.